# How do I return the data from google sheet on a web page?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have been trying to find a way of presenting only the cell-specific data stored on the google sheet on my web page. A sample of the data is as follows.

I'm not trying to embed the sheet here. I want it to look more presentable and well-formatted without the cell borders.

eg. The user enters the names of two products like "Wheet" and  "Oats". On clicking the SUBMIT button he must see only the cells of those two products on google sheet in two separate tables horizontally.

As of now, I have a webpage which has two inputs and a submit button,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.form-inline {  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-inline label {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

.form-inline input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.form-inline button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-inline button:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .form-inline input {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  
  .form-inline {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Product Details</h2>

<form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="product1">Product1:</label>
  <input type="product1" id="product1" placeholder="Enter first Product name" name="product1">
  <label for="product2">Product2:</label>
  <input type="product2" id="product2" placeholder="Enter second Product name" name="product2">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: This google sheet which has to be displayed is updated on regular basis by a number of people so the page must adapt accordingly.
Please suggest a way of doing this.

Also, I'm not very good at programming so if there's an open-source tool where less coding would be required and can be used to achieve this. Please do suggest.
like there's https://sketch2code.azurewebsites.net/ which converts sketch to code for a webpage.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use an actual database as the database, and not a google sheet? Especially if you're already implementing a web front-end to it.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you are right. But I can't make a call about this in this case. The Google sheet that I'm using is updated daily by a number of people and it has to be that way. Is there a way of using the Google sheet as the database?

Comment: It is possible. I see from your HTML that you are using a PHP file to handle your form action. Can you please share how you are handling it now, so I can help you?

Comment: Are you interested in a solution that inolves using an [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) to pull the data manually from serverside and then format them with HTML the way you desire?

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes please

Comment: Can you specify in which column the products are in the sheet.?And do you want to return to the website the whole row for those products?

Answer (score 0):

### [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) is interface that allows connecting client-side Javascript code with server-side [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) code

- Apps Script feature many handy functions for [accessing and processing of spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) data
- Web Apps need a `doGet()` function to create HTML output
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2) is a Javascript API that allows communication between the HTML part and the serverside code.gs part of the script project.
- Web Apps need to be [deployed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) to obtain a deployment URL
- This URL can either be simply opened in a browser or embedded in an alredy existing Webpage

**Sample code for finding values entered through a Web page form in a given spreadsheet and return the rows containing those values back to the Web page:**

code.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function findValues(value1, value2){
  var searchRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getValues();
  var productColumn = 1;
  var results = [];
  var products =searchRange.map(function(row){ return row[productColumn-1]});
  var firstIndex = products.indexOf(value1);
  if(firstIndex > -1){
    var firstRow = searchRange[firstIndex].filter(v => v);
    results.push(firstRow);
  }
  var secondIndex = products.indexOf(value2);
  if(secondIndex > -1){
    var secondRow = searchRange[secondIndex].filter(v => v);
    results.push(secondRow);
  }  
  if(results.length >0){
    results = JSON.stringify(results);
    Logger.log(results);
    return results;
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
         * {box-sizing: border-box;}
         .form-inline {  
         display: flex;
         flex-flow: row wrap;
         align-items: center;
         }
         .form-inline label {
         margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
         }
         .form-inline input {
         vertical-align: middle;
         margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
         padding: 10px;
         background-color: #fff;
         border: 1px solid #ddd;
         }
         .form-inline button {
         padding: 10px 20px;
         background-color: dodgerblue;
         border: 1px solid #ddd;
         color: white;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         .form-inline button:hover {
         background-color: royalblue;
         }
         @media (max-width: 800px) {
         .form-inline input {
         margin: 10px 0;
         }
         .form-inline {
         flex-direction: column;
         align-items: stretch;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="output"></div>
      <h2>Product Details</h2>
      <form class="form-inline">
         <label for="product1">Product1:</label>
         <input type="product1" id="product1" placeholder="Enter first Product name" name="product1">
         <label for="product2">Product2:</label>
         <input type="product2" id="product2" placeholder="Enter second Product name" name="product2">
         <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="passValuesToGoogle()">
      </form>
      <script>
         function passValuesToGoogle(){
         var product1 = document.getElementById("product1").value;
         var product2 = document.getElementById("product2").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayRows).withFailureHandler(onFailure).findValues(product1, product2);
         }
         function onFailure(error) {
         var div = document.getElementById('output');
         div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
         }
         
         function displayRows(values){
         console.log("success");
         if(values != null){
         values = JSON.parse(values);
         var div = document.getElementById('output');
         div.innerHTML = values[0] + "<br>" + values[1];
         }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please follow the procedure described in the linked documentation to deploy the WebApp with this code.